# Building a dictionary from a 2D list

Tags: python, dictionary, 2d

```
def somedict(dataList):
print(somedict([["monkeys", 5, 8, 3, 5], ["bananas", 2, 2, 3]]))
```

lets say I have something like above, where I want to take a 2D list and convert it into a dictionary without slicing.

So that the output would be:

```
{'monkeys': {'count': [5, 8, 3, 5]}, 'bananas': {'count': [2, 2, 3]}}
```

What are some methods for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use list unpacking with a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-dict_comprehension) to avoid explicit slicing or indexing:

```py
result = {fst: {'count': rest} for fst, *rest in data}
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
{'monkeys': {'count': [5, 8, 3, 5]}, 'bananas': {'count': [2, 2, 3]}}
```

Comment: No need to make the assignee of the `for` clause a list. A tuple would be more concise and efficient: `{fst: {'count': rest} for fst, *rest in data}`